# Join operation doesnt give columns of both the tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Hey I am trying to join two tables using find_by_sql method of rails, but i don't get the columns of the 'fb_ppl_pages' table:

```
"FbPage.find_by_sql("select * from fb_pages as t1 join fb_ppl_pages as t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id where t1.category='community'")"
```

How do i get the columns of both the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"FbPage.find_by_sql("select fb_pages.*,fb_ppl_pages.*  from fb_pages as t1 join fb_ppl_pages as t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id where t1.category='community'")"
```

selection `fb_pages.*,fb_ppl_pages.*` should give you all attributes